# How can I add an AdMob banner to a camera Activity, after startCamera() method(using the xzing library to scan QR Codes)?

Tags: java, android, camera, admob

I use a library called zxing from the package com.google.zxing.Result and me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView to scan QR codes in my new app, however I wasn't able to put a Admob banner at the bottom of the Camera Activity who scans the QR code, I don't know how to make it appear in that Camera Acvitity because it seems the camera activity doesn't have a layout XML to put the admob XML code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
MarshMallowPermission marshMallowPermission = new MarshMallowPermission(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

/*AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);*/

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
setContentView(mScannerView);

mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera
```

I tried this code to put the banner at the bottom of the activity camera but it doesn't work.

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1);
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
//AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
mainLayout.addView(mAdView,rlParams);
// Load the ad:
//AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The scanner view initializes, but it doesn´t show the banner, how can I call the camera Activity and put the banner there? your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public void QrScanner(View view) {


mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
setContentView(mScannerView);

mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `setContentView(mScannerView);`, you can inflate your own xml having `FrameLayout`, which you are already doing as `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

So add in that `activity_main.xml`, add `FrameLayout`, add one `LinearLayout` container to host the scanner and place one other `LinearLayout` as a container for AdMob banner.

add thee views in respective `LinearLayout` runtime by calling `mLinearLayoutContainerForScanner.addView(mScannerView);` and `mLinearLayoutContainerForAdMobBanner.addView(mScannerView)`.